# Save as Template is not enabled - move workflow between site collections

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have several list workflows I want to move from one domain to another. I can't use the `Export to Visio` because it says I need to use `Save as Template` instead.

I select the workflow in Designer and unfortunately the `Save as Template` button is NOT enabled, any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

From the screenshot, it seems like your workflow is a list workflow. In SharePoint 2010 designer, "Save as Template" option is available only for Re-usable workflows and is not available for List workflows, that is why it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the save as template button enabled the workflow must be reusable workflow.... with list workflow we can not have the save as a template enabled.